# optimizing part of code with array constructor

Tags: arrays, constructor, fortran, compiler-optimization

The following simple example code gives correct results.  However, I'd like to optimize it or make it more efficient.  The constructor array, y, that I create in order to generate the position line spacing works, but it is very clumsy looking and inconvenient since the numbers in it are very specific.  I want to make the numbers in the y array more general variables that depend on the earlier defined parameters in my code.  Here is the code and then I'll be more clear:

```
PROGRAM TestRuns
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i, j, k !matrix indices (i,j), spatial index k
INTEGER,PARAMETER :: n=5 !matrix size
REAL, PARAMETER :: a = -6, b =6 !end points of grid
REAL :: h !step size on position grid
REAL :: y(0:6) = (/(k, k=-6,6,2)/) ! generating spatial grid array
DOUBLE PRECISION :: M(n,n) !nxn matrix

h = (b-a)/(n+1)

DO i = 1,n
    DO j = 1,n
        IF (i .EQ. j) THEN
            M(i,j) = y(i)**2
        ELSE
            M(i,j) = 0
        END IF
    END DO
END DO

END PROGRAM TestRuns
```

Instead of having

```
 REAL :: y(0:6) = (/(k, k=-6,6,2)/)   ! this line of code works but is not helpful in generalizing my code at all.
```

I really want to write something more general such as :

```
 REAL :: y(0:n+1) = (/(k, k=a,b,h)/)
```

I always specify, a,b,n first in my code, so from these parameters I want to be able to then calculate h and the array y.  I don't want to have to automatically put the values of array y in by hand as I'm doing now.

Comment: Anything wrong with something like h=(b-a)/(n+1);y=[(a+k*h, k=0,n+1)] (apart from possible silly syntax errors)?

Comment: @IanBush I'm not sure.  I have to implement that in my code and see if there are any errors.  It may very well work fine so I'll let you know shortly.

Comment: @IanBush That worked!  Thanks for your help with my other problems and this one.  I get what you're doing there, its very efficient and clear now that I think about it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have discovered that your compiler doesn't like the line

```
REAL :: y(0:n+1) = (/(k, k=a,b,h)/)
```

Change it to

```
REAL :: y(0:n+1) = [(k, k=INT(a),INT(b),2)]
```

that is, make the lower and upper bounds for `k` into integers.  I doubt that you will ever be able to measure any increase in efficiency, but this change might appeal to your notions of nice-looking and convenient code.

You might also want to tweak the way you initialise `M`.  I'd have written your two loops as

```
M = 0.0
DO i = 1,n
   M(i,i) = y(i)**2
END DO
```

Overall, though, your question is a bit vague so I'm not sure how satisfactory this answer will be.  If not enough, clarify your question some more.

Comment: Is there anyway I can also remove the '2' in the y array and replace it with h?  Your method of using k = INT(a), INT(b) makes sense to me, thanks. However, is there anyway I can incorporate the value h into the y array? I calculate h based off of a,b,n; so I don't want to have to calculate it by hand everytime in order to get the number 2, since the value 2 is only for this run and not really that useful in general.

Your initialization of M looks way simpler and more efficient.  Your answer is very satisfactory for me, my only question left is about using the variable h. Thank you

Comment: *However, is there anyway I can incorporate the value h into the y array?*  Yes, replace `h` in the initialization statement with the expression `(b-a)/(n+1)` and sort out any errors such as wrong types.